# Remove Part of Typeahead Auto-Complete Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using Typeahead currently with great success, however im trying to add an icon to the array as so:

```
 "<i class='fa fa-facebook-square'></i> : Value 1",
 "<i class='fa fa-university'></i> : Value 2",
```

This shows up and works great in the bloodhound autocomplete, however, once clicked on, the following is within the text box.

```
> <i class='fa fa-facebook-square'></i> : Value 1
```

Is there anyway to avoid everything before the colon? But keep the dropdown box with the icon?

Current Typeahead JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// constructs the suggestion engine
var my_Suggestion_class = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  limit:40,
  local: $.map(daysOut, function(filtered_items) { return { value: filtered_items }; })
});

// kicks off the loading/processing of `local` and `prefetch`
my_Suggestion_class.initialize();
var typeahead_elem = $('.typeahead');
    typeahead_elem.typeahead({
      hint: true,
      highlight: true,
      minLength: 1
    },
    {
      // `ttAdapter` wraps the suggestion engine in an adapter that
      // is compatible with the typeahead jQuery plugin
          name: 'states',
          displayKey: '',
          source: my_Suggestion_class.ttAdapter()
    });
});
```

> HTML

```
            <form id="Form" action="" method="POST">
                <input id="id" name="id" type="text" class="form-control typeahead" style="text-align:center;" placeholder="">
                <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary homeSearchBtn" style="margin-top:-70px;"/><br/>     
            </form>
```

Comment: Alternatively, is it possible to remove the text input onfocus if its clicked on using the HTML5 input tag?